# Excel 2007 - Can you give groups names?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to group a set of rows then hide them. Once hidden can you make it display some sort of text message.

Like right now it just hides the rows.

It is not very obvious that the rows are hidden. Can you give a message to be shown when hidden sort of like regions in C#

```
region hi
// some code
#endregion
```

if you collapse(hide) the region you will see at least "hi" and no right off the bat that something is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expectation if you're grouping rows in Excel 2007 (on the Data tab/toolbar for those unfamiliar) is that you're grouping the data used to generate totals that are shown on the row immediately following the group. It's basically just a friendlier way to do what you've always been able to do with hiding rows/columns, and the grouping indicators in the margins are there to show you that something's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

For rows, you can add descriptive text to the row immediately above or below the rows containing the data you want to group. The description will be visible whether or not you have expanded the outline.