# Giving group indicators in Excel 2007 a name rather than numbers

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

This is a question relating to [Excel 2007 - Can you give groups names?](https://superuser.com/questions/159773/excel-2007-can-you-give-groups-names)

Is there any way of giving the grouping indicators a name rather than using 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: Is this what you meant? Or did you mean the indicators above the + signs when you have subtotals

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the Groups you can create in pivot tables?  If so, yes, you can.

After you create the group(s), you can select the group cell in the pivot table, then change its name in the formula edit space.  I hope this screenshot conveys the idea:

[image]